# Is it possible to localise a Maven artefactID?

Tags: maven, internationalization, l10n.js

Suppose a team in the US has a project containing this local library

```
<dependency><artifactId>garbage</artifactId></dependency>
```

but the UK version of our project has a `pom.xml` with this dependency listed instead:

```
</dependency><artefactId>rubbish</artefactId><dependency>
```

which specifies the localised build of the artefact.

Currently, a script takes the garbage project, builds it with UK localisation, but then has to patch up the .jar files after the fact so that the artefactId reflects the localisation, including if the string has been copied as part of the build process. This method has proven to be unreliable, however: Is there a way of migrating to a system which uses Maven, alone, to change the build ID depending on something like the `LANG` environment variable?

Or; is it not possible to introduce configuration into the `pom.xml` configuration file itself?

Comment: Just to clarify, it sounds like you need to build the same project, but swap out just one localization dependency .jar when you build? If so, how about a different profile per locale? Or even a multi module build?

Comment: Split it up so you generate rubbish in parallel to garbage.

Comment: Basically you should do the localisation within one build for all...areas...and don't rebuild artifacts...

Comment: @NickDeFazio No. We build the same project twice with different settings. For the UK version we then unzip the resultant artefact, adjust things like the artefactId, and re-zip it.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to build a project for different environments, you can use Maven Profiles:

http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

You can put different dependencies into different profiles and activate/deactivate the profiles in build process, on the command line or e.g. by marker files.